# Sublime Text 2 latex tools/New Build

Tags: compiling, gregorio, sublime-text

Please excuse me if I've posted this in the wrong area. I've just started using Sublime Text 2 for Latex with the LaTeX tools plugin. It's wonderful.
I'm using Mac ox 10.6.8

I'm wondering about adding an engine/build for processing `.gabc` files. Using `gregoriotex` I can run this in the command line `gregorio *.gabc` and it will process the file and output a `.tex` file.

I can also do this with TeXworks which uses an engine with this :

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
set filename = "$1"
set texname = "${filename:r}.tex"
gregorio "$filename"
echo "produced $texname"
```

any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Save the script you pasted in your question to a file, say for example at the file `/Users/yourusername/bin/run-gregorio` and give it execution permission (`chmod +x  /Users/yourusername/bin/run-gregorio`).
2. In Sublime Text 2, go to Tools -> Build System -> New Build System, this will create a buffer containing:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["make"]
   }
   ```
3. Edit it and change it to:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["/Users/yourusername/bin/run-gregorio", "$file_name"]
   }
   ```
4. Save it as `Gregorio.sublime-build` (Sublime Text 2 will pick the correct folder for you).

That's all! Now you can choose `Gregorio` as build system and then build a file. You will see the message `produced filename.tex` in the console.

Comment: Thank you, after wrestling with the path a bit it works like a charm.

Comment: I suggest to use `/usr/local/bin` folder instead. Mac OS X with MacPorts installed threats the shell script better :-) I mean, `$PATH` makes no problem.

Comment: I tried your method using this https://gist.github.com/macmadness86/5269856 script and it would not work. For some reason, Sublime Text 2 adds an extra slash to the export path. Works find in TexShop